# Erro Java Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, método, nullpointerexception

Pessoal preciso de uma ajuda com um erro em um método do meu código.

Basicamente eu tenho um FrameLayout que carrega duas fragments. Ao iniciar o APP ele carrega a primeira fragment com 3 TextEdits e um button. Ao clicar no buton, ele chama um método que está na activity pai e captura os dados da primeira fragment para armazenar em um BD. Nesse ponto ocorre a exception.

Esse é o erro:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl<init>.(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:249)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
    at com.example.caioferreira.agoravai.Activity.activity_primeiraExecucao.configuraEmpresa(activity_primeiraExecucao.java:42)
    at com.example.caioferreira.agoravai.Fragment.f_Empresa.registrarEmp(f_Empresa.java:43)
    at com.example.caioferreira.agoravai.Fragment.f_Empresa$1.onClick(f_Empresa.java:34)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612)
```

Código da activity onde está o método:

```
public class activity_primeiraExecucao extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_primeira_execucao);

        fragmentEmpresa = new f_Empresa();
        transaction.add(R.id.Frame_primeira_execucao,fragmentEmpresa );
        transaction.commit();

    }

    public f_SiTef fragmentSitef;
    public f_Empresa fragmentEmpresa;
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    public void configurafragment (){
        fragmentSitef = new f_SiTef();
        transaction.replace(R.id.Frame_primeira_execucao,fragmentSitef);
        transaction.commit();
    }
    public void configuraEmpresa (){

        c_Empresa valida = new c_Empresa();
        EditText rz = findViewById(R.id.EDT_razaoSocial);
        EditText numeroCNPJ = findViewById(R.id.EDT_CNPJ);
        EditText numLicenca = findViewById(R.id.EDT_licenca);
        String cnp = numeroCNPJ.getText().toString();
        String licenc = numLicenca.getText().toString();
        String razao = rz.getText().toString();
        boolean cnpvalido;
        valida.validaEmpresa(razao, cnp, licenc);

        if (valida.retorno== 2){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Por gentileza, preencha todos os campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else {
            cnpvalido=valida.isCNPJ(cnp);
            if (!cnpvalido){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "O CNPJ digitado não é válido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else if (valida.retorno == 1){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "A licença digitada não é valida para este CNPJ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            else {
                c_dbHelper db = new c_dbHelper( getApplicationContext());
                boolean grava = db.gravaEmpresa(db, razao, cnp, licenc);
                if(grava){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registro realizado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    //startActivity(intent);
                    //finish();
                    configurafragment();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Código da Fragment:

```
public class f_Empresa extends Fragment {
    activity_primeiraExecucao activity;
    public Button btnEmpresa;
    public f_Empresa() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_empresa, container, false);
        btnEmpresa = view.findViewById(R.id.BTN_registrar_empresa);
        btnEmpresa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                registrarEmp(v);
            }
        });
        return view;

    }

    public void registrarEmp(View v) {
        activity = new activity_primeiraExecucao();
        activity.configuraEmpresa();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver.

Tirei o Button da Fragment e movi direto para a activity colocando todas as chamadas e referências de View direto na activity.